# Django aggregate(sum error

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to sum a complete field after filtering objects using pk.

**Views.py**

```
def items(request, pk):
    current_user = request.user
    selected_itemz = get_object_or_404(ItemIn, pk=pk)
    all_cats = Category.objects.all()
    cat_count = all_cats.count()
    item_count = ItemIn.objects.values_list('item_name', flat=True).distinct().count()  # returns a list of tuples..
    #all_units = Item.objects.aggregate(Sum('item_quantity'))['item_quantity__sum']
    ItemOut_table = ItemOut.objects.all().filter(item_name=selected_itemz)
    ItemOut_quantity = ItemOut_table.aggregate(Sum('item_quantity'))['item_quantity__sum']

    context = {
        #'all_units': all_units,
        'item_count': item_count,
        'cat_count': cat_count,
        'current_user': current_user,
        'ItemOut_quantity': ItemOut_quantity,
        'selected_itemz':selected_itemz,
    }

    return render(request, 'townoftech_warehouse/item_details.html', context)
```

Then I used an extra filter that I created which is `subtract` in my HTML

**HTML**

```
  <br>
  <br>
  <p align="right">
  الكمية الموجودة:
       {{ selected_itemz.item_quantity|subtract:ItemOut_quantity }}
      </p>
  <br>
  <br>
```

and here is the `tempaltetags` file

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def subtract(value, arg):
    return value - arg
```

Now I get the error :

```
TypeError at /item/1/
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Your filter is raising error because value of args is none and this is because when itemout table does not contain any object it's aggregate function return None instead of zero. Update your ItemOut_quantity to zero if it is None.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you sum over an **empty queryset**, then the result of the sum is **`None`**. Then later in your view you subtract that `None` from an integer, but Python has no way to subtract `None` from an integer, hence the error.

You can use `or 0`, to replace `None` with zero in your view:

```
ItemOut_quantity = ItemOut_table.aggregate(sum=Sum('item_quantity'))['sum'] or 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Django uses Coalesce function to achieve this under the hood. You can use it as well.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce


ItemOut_quantity = ItemOut_table.aggregate(
    sum=Coalesce(Sum('item_quantity'), 0)
).get('sum')
```