# Django Coalesce returns null if no rows are found

Tags: django

I'm using the [`Coalesce` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) to prevent an aggregate `Sum` from returning `None`

```
Coalesce(Sum('ext_price'), 0)
```

The problem is that if no rows are found it still returns null. Is there a way to modify the function so it returns zero if no rows are found?

```
class Coalesce(Func):
    """Return, from left to right, the first non-null expression."""
    function = 'COALESCE'

    def __init__(self, *expressions, **extra):
        if len(expressions) < 2:
            raise ValueError('Coalesce must take at least two expressions')
        super().__init__(*expressions, **extra)
```

By having no rows I mean

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.none()
total = queryset.aggregate(total=Coalesce(Sum('total'), Value(0)).get('total')
total == None  # True
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wrap the value in a `Value` object:

```
from django.db.models import Coalesce, Value

Coalesce(Sum('ext_price'), Value(0))
```

You can implement your own `Coalesce` function, for example:

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

class CoalesceZero(Coalesce):

    def __init__(self, *expressions, **extra):
        super().__init__(*expressions, Value(0), **extra)
```

In that case, you can thus use your `CoalesceZero`, and you no longer need to write `Value(0)` as last value.

**EDIT**: If you have an aggregation, that of course this is `COALESCE` will not be evaluated. You can then use a simple `or 0` in your Python code:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.none()
total = queryset.aggregate(total=Sum('total')).get('total') or 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I've updated the OP with more info

Comment: @bdoubleu: but that is not an annotation, that is an aggregation over an empty queryset.

Comment: Just found [your answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50316334/8741781) from 2018.. just had to slightly change the wording

Answer (score 0):

Willem's answer above on aggregations is great if you just have a few times; if you have to do that in a lot of places you can do something like this:

```
class AggregateCoalesceMixin:
    @staticmethod
    def aggregate_coalesce(
        aggregate: Dict[str, Any],
        default_from_value: Optional[Any] = None,
        default_to_value: Optional[Any] = 0,
        default_map: Optional[Dict[str, Tuple[Any, Any]]] = None,
    ) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        for k, v in aggregate.items():
            if default_map and k in default_map:
                if v == default_map[k][0]:
                    aggregate[k] = default_map[k][1]
                    continue
            elif v == default_from_value:
                aggregate[k] = default_to_value
        return aggregate
```

Which you can use like so:

```
aggregate_result = {"item_1": None, "item_2": 20}
aggregate_result = self.aggregate_coalesce(aggregate_result)
>> {"item_1": 0, "item_2": 20}
```

And if you need more control, can provide a map of coalescent values:

```
aggregate_result = {"item_1": None, "item_2": '', "item_3": 20}
map = {"item_1": (None, 0), "item_2": ('', 'NA'), "item_3": (None, 0)}
aggregate_result = self.aggregate_coalesce(aggregate_result, default_map=map)
>> {"item_1": 0, "item_2": 'NA', "item_3": 20}
```