# Sum of two calculated annotation in django

Tags: django, django-database

```
.annotate(
        waste=Sum("processings__chunks__waste"),
        completed_waste=models.Task.get_completed_waste_annotation(),
        tooling_time=Sum("processings__chunks__tooling_time"),
        completed_tooling_time=models.Task.get_completed_tooling_time_annotation(),
        processing_time=Sum("processings__chunks__processing_time"),
        completed_processing_time=models.Task.get_completed_processing_time_annotation(),
        total_time=F("tooling_time") + F("processing_time"),
        completed_total_time=F("completed_tooling_time") + F("completed_processing_time"),
    )
```

I've this annotate, the problem is in the last two fields `total_time` and `completed_total_time`, when one of the fields `tooling_time`, `processing_time` is None, I get None in both of the fields.

Comment: maybe this helps with Coalesce: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265850/django-coalesce-returns-null-if-no-rows-are-found

Comment: Nope, becouse I need that if both are none, I need it to be none

Answer (score 0):

The solution at the end was to calculate that two fields in the serializer with `serializers.SerializerMethodField()`